# Conditional if statement inside where in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following SQL query to be translated to LINQ

```
string qWhere;
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-01");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-03");

if(manual == true)
{
    qWhere = " deliveryDate>=" + startDate + " and deliveryDate<=" + endDate; 
}
else
{
    qWhere = "deliveryDate>=" + DateTime.Now;
}

string sqlQuery = "select * from LoadingOrder where " + qWhere;
```

can anyone help me to translate this query to LINQ, table LoadingOrder have million rows.

Many thanks

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: EF to Sql or EF to Entities?

Comment: A hair-splitting detail: It's better to assign `DateTime.Now` to a variable and use that variable in the query instead of `DateTime.Now`. In SQL it translates to GETDATE(). That means that the date may vary by milliseconds or more for each comparison. The chances are small that this would affect the outcome, but it's best if every record is being compared to the same date/time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-01");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-03");
bool manual = ...;

loadingOrders.Where(
    o => o.DeliveryDate >= startDate &&
    o.DeliveryDate <= endDate &&
    manual ||
    o.DeliveryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
    !manual);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing some parenthesis there?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, if you take in account the precedence of operators, then no.

Comment: Code is **read** much more than it is **written**. As such, the parentheses may aid readability.

Answer (score 2):

If it was just the one condition then you could have two separate queries instead of one query. I think that's a lot easier to read and follow then placing the conditional inside the query itself.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
if(manual)
    result = LoadingOrders.Where(s=> s.deliveryDate >= startDate && s.deliveryDate <= endDate);
else
    result = LoadingOrders.Where(s=> s.deliveryDate >= now);
```

Suppose the query has lots of conditions and the "delivery date" condition is the only one that changes. In that case you probably wouldn't want to have two entire versions of the query with just one difference. In that case, you can create that one condition separately.

To do that you would create a `Func<LoadingOrder, bool>` - a function that takes a `LoadingOrder` and returns true or false. And then you would assign whichever condition you want to check for to that function.

```
Func<LoadingOrder, bool> deliveryDateCondition;
if(manual)
    deliveryDateCondition = loadingOrder => 
        loadingOrder.deliveryDate >= startDate && loadingOrder.deliveryDate <= endDate;
else
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    deliveryDateCondition = loadingOrder => loadingOrder.deliveryDate >= now;
}
```

Now `deliveryDateCondition` is function that takes a `LoadingOrder` and returns true or false. You can add that function into your LINQ query, and it works regardless of which function was selected.

```
var result = LoadingOrders.Where(loadingOrder => deliveryDateCondition(loadingOrder) 
    && ...some other condition...
    && ...some other condition...);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var query = from e in db.LoadingOrder
        where (e.deliveryDate >= startDate && e.deliveryDate <= endDate && manual)
        || (e.deliveryDate >= now)
        select e;
```

OR

```
var query = db.LoadingOrder.Where(x => (x.deliveryDate >= startDate && x.deliveryDate <= endDate && manual) || (x.deliveryDate >= now));
```